# What SharePoint Column is used for a Video?

Tags: 2013, column, video

Is there a built-in column that is used for a video asset?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. You'd have to use an attachment as a List item, otherwise you'd have to set up an asset library and use that asset attachment in a hyperlink column. Alternatively, you could do some development that would customize a form that users can fill out that would upload a video to an asset library and also post it to a List item using the new hyperlink of the asset.